# Parse value of input text to GTM Variable macro?

Tags: javascript

On my site there is a text area for input of login information. I wanted to capture the information (i.e. random ID) via GTM Custom Javascript.

I have written a few lines of code and it worked. Yet I want to know if there're other ways to accomplish the same fest by modifying the codes.

I wrote in the structure of function () {....} and used it to create a variable, and use it as a macro in my tag.

```
function ()
{ 
var idSelect = 
document.querySelector('input[name="xxxxxxxxx"]').value.trim();
return idSelect;  
}
```

Comment: it is unclear to me what you intend to do exactly, or what mean with "accomplish the same fest".

Comment: Thanks 2x2p. I want to know if there are other codes that can do the same trick. For instance, if we can adapt jquery instead to write the codes for GTM custom javascript.

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What is GTM Custom Javascript? What do you want answered?